# How to fix an element while scroll reach it upper point

Tags: jquery

I wanted to know how to fix div element when we scroll through it. I it should be at it original place but when we scroll and come to it's point, then it should be fixed on that place. CSS `position:fixed;` don't work here.

I have seen many sites using this technique, may be it's JQuery. http://9gag.com/ < This is a site using that technique, you can see on right sidebar when you scroll down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position:fixed` is used here.

Every element what you want to fix have 2 states - with `position:absolute` and `position:fixed`. And every element what you want to fix has page scroll value that change state from one to another

---

```
var 
Node = $('yourDIV'),
Func = function(){
 var Top = $(document).scrollTop();
 if(Top > 300) Node.css({'position':'fixed'});
 else Node.css({'position':'absolute'});
}

$(window).on('scroll',function(){ Func(); });
```

Comment: Hello Rustam, i tried it but it didn't worked. Can you please explain more clearly and review the code you gave.

Comment: It's principle, not code. For code you need to set additional styles (top/left/right/bottom) for each class with absolute/fixed position - it's like you want.